# How to estimate GreenPAK speed limits?

Tags: programmable-logic, pld

I am considering using a SLG46826 GreenPAK PLD for a simple digital design running at 40 MHz. Basically output a 40 MHz external clock and generate a properly synchronized pulse now and then. In the [datasheet](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/slg46826-datasheet?r=1572991) I can only find the internal delays in table 10. I can't however find the setup/hold times for anything and IO timings. The only design that barely mentions "tens of MHz" is [AN-1178](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/apn/1178-practical-use-greenpak-pulse-counter-frequency-counter-thermometer-voltmeter).

The part is done in a 180 nm process and has a 25 MHz internal oscillator but how can I make sure that it will operate at 40 MHz? Rely entirely on the simulator built into the designer software?

Answer (score 0):

40 MHz is probably too high for the SLG46826. You may confirm in the GreenPAK section of the Renesas web site.

Comment: zapta - Thanks for trying to help. However this isn't a clear answer to the question "how can I make sure that it will operate at 40 MHz?". It sounds more like a guess. We want people to explain their answers. Can you [edit] the answer to add any specific evidence that 40 MHz is too high? Also, suggesting people to look on a website is also not adequate for an answer here. If the statement is made on that website, please quote the relevant passage & [link to the document](/help/referencing) containing that quote. || You can see more site rules in the [tour] & [help]. TY